# Slack API - set bot display name in API call dynamically

Tags: slack-api, zapier

I'm writing a bot to replace a Zapier script. When setting up messages from Zapier to Slack, it's possible to set the bot name and icon for each individual message. I'm trying to replicate this but I can't work it out.

According to the [slack docs][1] it is possible to set the name by specifying the following parameters: `as_user:true, username:BOT_NAME`.

I've tried doing this with both the user and bot Oauth tokens and get these responses:

```
  "error":"invalid_arguments","deprecated_argument":"as_user"

  "error":"missing_scope","needed":"chat:write:bot","provided":"identity.basic"
```

It looks like the only scope available is `chat:write` and `chat:write:bot` has been deprecated.

How is Zapier able to dynamically set bot names?
[1]: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: When it comes to authorship of messages in slack, you need to request the `chat:write.customize` scope. Once you are done with that you can now proceed to configure the username for a particular message using the `chat.PostMessage` method in your case.